# How to use pandas extract to remove string in a pandas column

Tags: regex, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'test':['test?_Apple','test?_Banana', 'test?_limon']})
```

And I want to remove the `test?_` string from test columns values to get this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'test':['Apple','Banana', 'limon']})
```

I am trying:

```
d['test'] = d['test'].str.extract(r'test?_(.*)')
```

but it returns `NAN`

Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: Use `d['test'] = d['test'].str.extract(r'test\?_(.*)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape `?` because special regex character:

```
d['test'] = d['test'].str.extract(r'test\?_(.*)')
```